# DatetimeIndex with MultipleLocator gives incorrect axis labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

And I'm doing a stacked bar:

```
df.plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(12,12))
```

It renders correctly, except the x axis is very crowded:

[image]

I tried the following:

```
loc = plt.ticker.MultipleLocator(base=7)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
```

But it spreads out the dates, rather than picking every 7th, so the labels are wrong:

[image]

How can I get what I want (Only one x label every 7 days)?

Comment: Can you test this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50677718/2901002) ?

Comment: `locator = AutoDateLocator()
locator.intervald[HOURLY] = [3]  # only show every 3 hours
`
Since the official website has the above description, why don't you try coding it as follows?
`
locator.intervald[DAILY] = [7]

Comment: @jezrael Thanks, that seems to sort it out. Weird that it makes it categorical!